# Read from texture in compute shader

Tags: wgpu-rs

I am trying to read (and write) to a texture in my compute shader. And getting the following message:

```
Read-write and read-only storage textures are not allowed by webgpu, they require the native only feature TEXTURE_ADAPTER_SPECIFIC_FORMAT_FEATURES
```

Reading from a texture in a compute shader is extremely useful, surely there must a way to accomplish this in some other way.

#### Edit:

I am writing a raytracer eerily similar to this one.
https://github.com/jgrazian/wgpu-raytracer.

And this used to [be possible in the past](https://github.com/jgrazian/wgpu-raytracer/blob/1168d3c27b664313871d3f427458ae03070ccb5e/src/pipelines/compute.rs#LL33C1-L34C1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading from a texture in a compute shader is possible when binding the texture as a normal [`Texture`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/enum.BindingType.html#variant.Texture) (not as a [`StorageTexture`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/enum.BindingType.html#variant.StorageTexture)) and then using[`textureLoad`](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#textureload) on it: https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu/issues/2735